# Nullspace of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let ${\bf A} \in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ Vandermonde matrix, $N>M$ $$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
\alpha_1 & \alpha_{2} & \dots & \alpha_{N} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\alpha_1^{M-1} & \alpha_{2}^{M-1} & \dots & \alpha_{N}^{M-1}
\end{array}\right)$$and ${\bf B} \in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$: ${\bf {B}}={\bf {diag}}(e^{j\alpha_1},...,e^{j\alpha_{N}})$. Let ${\bf {C=AB}}$, I have two questions: $(1)$ What effect does the matrix $\bf {B}$ have on the null space of $\bf {A}$, both have nice structures. $(2)$ Is the nullspace of $\bf {C}$ somehow related to the null space of $\bf {A}$.

Comment: What _effect_ could $B$ have on the null space of $A$, which is an immutable mathematical object?

Comment: Also please specify $A$; Vandermonde matrices are usually considered to be square, and there is no universal agreement the entries are arranged (ones in which row or column?).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I updated the question to show the structure of vandermonde matrix.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** (1) By changing the $\alpha$s, certainly the null space of $A$ changes as well, but note that you cannot infer the value $\alpha_k$ from $e^{j\alpha_k}$, thus $B$ is a function of $A$, but not the converse. So, it's hard to talk about the effect of $B$ on the null space of $A$. (2) $B$ is invertible. So the null space of $C$ is just $B^{-1}\ker(A)=\{B^{-1}v: v\in\ker A\}$.

Comment: entries of $A$ are related to the entries of $B$. I updated the question to show the structure of $A$.

Comment: @user63552 Still, the null space of $A$ is controlled by the $\alpha$s, not $B$.